# How to map a number to 1, so that number/2 === 0.5 and so on?

Tags: javascript, percentage

I'm making a HTTP call and I get two values. I need to map the highest value to 1, because I'm using a progress bar library  that only accepts values between 0 and 1. It would be something like:

let delivered = 1000;

let pending = 250;

then I need to substract those two values (I'll get 75 in this example) but I need this value to be 0.75.

if delivered = 1250 and pending = 0, then I need a total variable to be 1, so that the progress bar span to 100%.

Here's a 'working' snippet:

```js
let delivered, pending, cumplidas, progress;

fetch("http://157.230.190.251/api/v1/cmodels/secure/dashboard")
.then(function(response) {
 return response.json();
})
.then(function(json) {
    console.log(json)
     cumplidas = json.kpis[0]

     delivered = cumplidas.entregadas;
     pending = cumplidas.pendientes;

     progress = delivered - pending;
    console.log(progress)

})

var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(progreso, {
  strokeWidth: 6,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  color: '#FFEA82',
  trailColor: '#eee',
  trailWidth: .6,
  svgStyle:  {
        display: 'block',

        width: '100%'
    },
    text: {

        value: '75', // here I need to insert 'progress' variable, not this hardcoded value


        style: {

            color: '#f00',
            position: 'absolute',
            left: '50%',
            top: '50%',
            padding: 0,
            margin: 0,
            // You can specify styles which will be browser prefixed
            transform: {
                prefix: true,
                value: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
            }
        }}

});

bar.animate(.75);  /* Number from 0.0 to 1.0 . Here I need to instert 'progress' variable, not this hardcoded value*/
```

```css
 #progreso {
            margin: 20px;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.tutorialjinni.com/progressbar.js/1.1.0/progressbar.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="progreso">

    </div>
    <script>


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: show us some input and desired output.

Comment: Are you trying to describe *division*?

Comment: is it an ergative concept?

Comment: I inserted a "working" snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll achieve that this way:

```
let progress = delivered / (pending + delivered);
```

Comment: thanks. however, it's not the right value, I'm having a basic aritmethic problem...

if I print I get this 

delivered: 1500,pending: 500

and for progress I get this : 0.00029991002699190244

Which doesn't correspond (I'm aware my question is so dumb..)

Comment: Well, can you show me more? It seems that 1500 / (1500 + 500) is equal to 1500/2000 which is 0.75 (your 75%). Are you sure you don't have any calculation issues?

Comment: You are completely right, buddy. I forgot to parse to integer 'pending' and 'delivered' variables, I was getting a concatenation instead a sum.